# HTML element size issue

Tags: html

```
<SPAN>Instuction » &nbsp;</SPAN><INPUT id=inst10008 size=38><A jQuery1249838079711="50"><IMG style="FLOAT: right" border=0 alt=select src="../../Content/image/selectbutton.gif"></A>
```

I have above in div so it is like "TEXT TextBOX Link"

Link is floating right so would be at end

- Issue is i need textbox size to fill
  all available space

  In different resolution textbox size
  would varry

  Size attribute makes it fixed width

  I tried Width but as i have link
  floating right it is not working as i
  need it

How could it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try floating the first two items left instead?  Like this...

```
<div>
  <span style="float:left">text...</span>
  <input type="textbox" style="float:left;width:100%;" />
  <a href="blah">link text </a>
</div>
```